# How can I create an exfat partition that can be mounted without root?

Tags: linux, filesystems, terminal, command

I am using "mkfs.exfat /dev/sdb1" and it works beautifully, except only a root user can modify the contents. I have looked through all of the options I can find for mkfs and cannot figure this out. Thanks.

Comment: Whether or not a filesystem can be mounted as a normal user is no question of how it has been created, but whether the `/etc/fstab` contains the `user` option for this file system.

Comment: ahhh... that explains why I can't figure it out lol. Care to elaborate?

Comment: ahhh....have you consulted the man page which gives a pretty fair description of your options

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of points that might help clear this up for you.

First, the exFAT filesystem, unlike other filesystems you're used to, has no provision for storing the metadata that describes *ownership* and *permissions*. Consequently, ownership and permissions are created when the partition is ***mounted***, and these cannot be changed unless or until the partition is re-mounted. See `man mount.exfat-fuse` for a description of the parameters which define the ownership and permissions values assigned at mount-time.

The Linux utilities involved in the mounting process for exFAT partitions default to `root` ownership for everything, and default `umask` values for permissions. This is why you see questions from time-to-time from people frustrated that they cannot change ownership or permissions on a mounted exFAT volume; i.e. `chown` and `chmod` simply do not work on a mounted exFAT volume.

Second, your **title question** addresses how to mount an exFAT filesystem as someone other than `root`. This question is unrelated to the question addressed above. A non-root user **is allowed** to mount an exFAT partition if the `user` (or `users`) option is specified (for example) in the `/etc/fstab` file in the fourth field (`fs_mntops`) of an entry. This option is *filesystem-independent*, and so is not limited to exFAT volumes.

The user accomplishes this mount as follows:

```bash
$ mount /mount/point
```

The user is also allowed to `umount` the mounted volume.

Comment: You may also be able to mount it with udisks or fusemount